# What word is used to describe someone who pleases the crowd and doesn't stand for integrity

Tags: single-word-requests

What word describes someone who pleases the crowd and doesn't stand for what is right or justice? - I'm thinking of corrupt, but it doesn't fit well.

For example, Tom is a_______;  he doesn't seem to have a firm ground on what is right. He only says what will sway the crowd to like him more. He doesn't care whether his statement are factually right or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't stand for integrity"?

Comment: Modern journalism is done out of pleasing people?! Well, I never!

Comment: We have fairly strict criteria for this sort of question, I'm afraid. Please see tag help for [word-requests](/tags/single-word-requests/info) or [phrase-requests](/tags/phrase-requests/info), especially the check-list at the end, and [edit] your question to improve it. A sample sentence with a blank in it for others in the community to fill in is so useful that it's explicitly mentioned in the help as being needed. We also need to know whether you want a noun ("He is a ...") or an adjective ("He is ..."), although the question does lean towards an adjective.

Comment: Tom is a Donald J Trump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities immediately come to mind...

> **rabble-rouser** [(Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rabble-rouser)
> *a person who says, writes, or does things that make crowds of people excited or angry, usually intentionally in order to make them act in a particular way*

> **populist**  [(Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/populist)
> *trying to be popular with ordinary people and to represent their ideas and opinions*

Note that ***rabble-rouser*** is much more informal, and is *always* pejorative, but ***populist*** is *sometimes* (though not often) used approvingly, and it *can* appear in quite formal contexts.

---

There are also lots of pejorative terms specifically relevant to *politicians* who will endorse anything if they think it will win votes - *political **opportunist, windsock, weathercock, chameleon,...***

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer has some good options, but I think another choice is

> **Demagogue** [(Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/demagogue)
>
> *a person, especially a political leader, who wins support by exciting the emotions of ordinary people rather than by having good or morally right ideas*

I think it keeps the negative connotations of rabble-rouser, but without the informality.